# How to extract cookies from pcap files

Tags: cookies, wireshark

I already have a pcap file. I know that when I enter a website, my userid and password is sent through unsecured http protocol. I would like to extract the cookies from the pcap files and import them into my browser(Firefox) to observe what happens. I already filtered out using http in wireshark, but still I get a lot of packets. How do i extract the exact cookies and import the cookies in my Firefox?

Comment: This is not a security question but a pure Wireshark use question. Your answer is in the documentation.

Comment: You can `Follow the TCP Stream` for each packet by loading `.pcap` file in Wireshark and analysing them to get the information exactly you will see in that cookie. By the way, For what purpose exactly you want to do that.

Comment: It was for a college project. The professor was teaching us how to hijack cookies from pcap packets.